# How to revert/roll back to an earlier commit in Foundry Code Repo

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I use Foundry Code Repository. How could I revert back to an earlier commit? I am sure this is possible but it's really hard to find the place to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this steps to go to the place where you could revert.

1. You are in Code Repo, go to the tab "Branches" on top of the UI
2. Click on the name of the branch to view it. The way the UI shows the name makes it super not clear that it's clickable. In the example from the screenshot, you click on branch "develop"
3. After that you will see all the past commits and you could revert back to what you want

hth

[image]

[image]